# Grab loaded webpage URL? WKWebView macOS

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    self.urlText.stringValue = String(describing: webView.url!)
}
```

This does not work 100% of the time.

An example would be when I navigate to reddit. I click a thread and it changes URL which is fine, but if I click the reddit home button, it doesn't change URL to www.reddit.com even after it is 100% loaded.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What else is going on in your view controller? I'm not able to reproduce your problem with the code below. Have you tried this in an isolated project?

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var urlLabel: NSTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let req = URLRequest(url:
            URL(string: "https://reddit.com")!)

        webView.load(req)        
    }


    @IBAction func getUrlClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let url = webView.url else { return }
        urlLabel.stringValue = url.absoluteString

        print("url: \(String(describing: webView.url!))")
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```